# How do I cycle through a CheckBoxList and submit values to the database for each checked value?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to insert checkboxlist values into SQL Server using a stored procedure. I'm getting this error

> Item In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insertquestionnarie] 
    (@interestid int)

    INSERT INTO [a_abacus].[dbo].[joininterest]
    VALUES (@interestid)
```

Here's my vb code:

```
 Protected Sub cmdsubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsubmit.Click

        Dim strConnString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("a_abacus").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_insertquestionnarie", con) 'references connectionstring and calls store procedure'
        cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure 'sets default to be stored procedure'
        lblmessage.Text = String.Empty

        Dim Item As ListItem
        lblMessage.Text = ""
        For Each Item In chkboxinterest.Items
            If Item.Selected = True Then
                con.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@interestid", Item.Value)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'for updating database'
                lblmessage.Text = "Successfull"
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            Else
                lblmessage.Text = "Error"
            End If
            con.Close()
        Next
    End Sub
```

Here's the aspx page markup:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkboxinterest" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" 
            Width="650px">
       <asp:ListItem class="chkbox" runat="server" Text="Aerobics" Value="1" />
       <asp:ListItem class="chkbox" runat="server" Text="Antiques & Collectibles" Value="2" />
       <asp:ListItem class="chkbox" runat="server" Text="Arts & Crafts" Value="3" />
       <asp:ListItem class="chkbox" runat="server" Text="Astronomy" Value="4" />
       <asp:ListItem class="chkbox" runat="server" Text="Auto Racing" Value="5" />
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: Does this change anything `<asp:ListItem class="chkbox" runat="server" Value="5">Auto Racing</asp:ListItem>` ? It is strange that you cannot get the value.

Comment: also Tim thanks for the response however that did not change anything

Comment: Are you sending @interestname or @interestid? Does the proc require both?

Comment: Are you getting an exception or just your code that says "error"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, there is no need to add parameters to your SQL Command so often.**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@interestid", Item.Value)
```

You need to change that.

Before your loop, add the parameter (without value) to the SqlCommand. However, declare it as type SQLDbType.int.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@interestid", SQLDBType.Int)
```

Then, in your loop, you just need to change the value of the SQL Command.

```
cmd.Parameters("@interestid").Value = Item.Value
```

Remove `cmd.Parameters.Clear()`

**Second, Remove con.Open() and con.Close() from your loop.**

You only need to open the connection before the loop, and close it after the loop.

**Third, perform some input validation on Item.Value**

Is it really in the range that you think it is? Either use a RangeValidator in your markup, or perform some custom logic in the code-behind. At the very least, do this: `CInt(Item.Value)`

**Fourth, your Alter Procedure statement is missing the required `AS` keyword**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762.aspx

```
Alter MyProc (@param int) **AS** Select * from Products
```